# Code Rush: Keyboard Shortcut to Change Member Scope

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, coderush, refactorpro

When using CodeRush/Refactor Pro, I can use my mouse to toggle a context menu to change the scope of a member.  By default, pressing CRTL+' doesn;t toggle this menu.

Is there anyway to achive this using a keyboard shortcut? A soltuion involving CRTL+' would be ideal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can toggle the scope using `ALT + up/down arrow`

Place the caret inside the method or on the same line and try it. DevExpress offers a shortcut cheat sheet [here](http://www.devexpress.com/Downloads/Visual_Studio_Add-in/files/CodeRushShortcutsAndTemplates.pdf) that you might find useful.